# I cant install ffmpeg binary driver on my laravel project

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I am trying to install ffmpeg binary on my laravel application but I am getting this error. Could not find a matching version of package php-ffmpeg/binary-driver. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev). I am using laravel 6.4.1

My composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "pawlox/video-thumbnail": "^1.0",
    "lakshmaji/thumbnail": "^1.4",
    "pion/laravel-chunk-upload": "^1.3",
    "pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg": "^5.0"
},

"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/BinaryDriver.git"
}]
}
```

composer require php-ffmpeg/binary-driver=dev-master
Any Solutions. Thanks

Comment: do as it says, install the php extention "php-ffmpeg". if on ubuntu run `sudo apt-get install php-ffmpeg`

Comment: am working on windows 10

Comment: Check this for some direction https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

Answer (score 0):

php-ffmpeg is not a front-end package, so you have to install it by your composer and it is on composer.json not package.json. you can find windows version of php-ffmpeg here:
[For Windows users: Please find the binaries at](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

Comment: it's not a package at all, it's a php extention, a binary package

Comment: @Ebi it is composer.json not package.json. my bad